# Sublime Key Binding Arguments

Tags: sublimetext3, settings

Sublime's key bindings accept arguments, where can I find the list of arguments I can pass for user defined key bindings?

Documentation doesn't make it clear, google is not helping, I can't find source of this dictionary, where is it all being defined? How can I review what I can use or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "arguments" here? The contents of `args` that you provide to the commands that you're trying to bind?

Comment: Sorry yeah, meant the keys of the `args` values in the json that keybindings use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments that a command takes depend on the command itself, which is true not only for default commands that ship with Sublime but also any commands added by plugins or third party packages.

The unofficial documentation has a [list of commands](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/commands.html) internal to Sublime, including what they do and what arguments they take which can be of help here. For example, given this text:

> **new_window**
>      Opens a new window.

The command `new_window` takes no arguments. On the other hand:

> **expand_selection**
>   Extends the selection up to predefined limits.
>
> - **to** [Enum]: Values: bol, hardbol, eol, hardeol, bof, eof, brackets, line, tag, scope, indentation.

The `expand_selection` command takes an argument named `to`, and also has a list of predefined values that it can take, e.g. `"to": "bol"` to expand the selection to the beginning of the line.

To my knowledge there's no official list of internal commands with the exception that they're used in the default key bindings (which appear in the left hand pane of the key bindings window when you open it).

Third party packages that define commands sometimes outline them in their README file, but many also choose to go the same route as Sublime and just document them in the key bindings files.

It's also possible for commands to appear in other places (e.g. in menus and in the command palette), which is another place to look. You can use the internal `View Package File` command to view `sublime-command` and `sublime-menu` files to see what they're doing as well, if you're curious.

Lastly, if you open the Sublime console and enter the command `sublime.log_commands(True)`, Sublime will log commands as they execute, telling you what they are and what arguments they took. Note however that there is currently an issue in more recent builds where commands from the command palette are not always logged.

Comment: thank you, that's by far the most info I could find. Sadly I was looking for a comprehensive list of inbuilt commands to see full-breadth of what I am allowed to do by default, particularly regarding any 'hidden' commands, but from what I gather only implemented commands can be picked up and it very well may be the complete list too; weird that there's no documentation for this stuff. All said and done, hope your answer saves someone from gritting their teeth to dust!

Comment: I don't think there are any hidden commands; at least in the core. Packages can implement commands and not bind them if they don't want them visible (though you could introspect the code to see what they're doing), but if a command is hidden, it's probably for a reason.

Comment: this was useful: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/1/commands

Comment: Note that the names of commands from ST1 are in a different format, may or may not still exist or take the same arguments.